# Redirect all SSH traffic through a "middleman" server

Tags: ssh, rsync, tunnel

**this is my setup right now:**
A. My NAS with static IP, reachable via SSH from the Internet (OS X)
B. a VPS (Ubuntu Server)
C. a dedicated server (Gentoo)

**My question:**
Due to bad peering i want to tunnel all my SSH traffic from A to C through B (rsync, flexget,... running on A)

I know how to rsync using a tunnel but i can't really figure out how to make it happen so it's pushing all the traffic through the tunnel.

thanks!

grimes

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `netcat` as an `ssh` proxy command. Append this to the file `~/.ssh/config` on Host sourcehost:

```
Host targethost
    ProxyCommand ssh -q viahost nc -q0 C 22
```

Then `ssh targethost` on Host sourcehost should tunnel via Host viahost. Rsync etc. should also work. Consider to use ControlMaster like this:

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath $HOME/.ssh/tmp/%h_%p_%r
```

Answer (score 0):

Tunelling ssh connection is quite easy. Step by step well written tutorial is [here](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html).
You need to setup tunnel on the middle machine.

Then when you connect from A to B on specific port you will automatically connect to C.

If you want to pass all traffic - like https via tunnel you will need to install squid proxy and redirect traffic from 443 port through yout tunnel.