# Establish SSH connection via SSH tunnel in a single command

Tags: networking, ssh, tunnel

I'm trying to connect to one of my internal computers (private ip) using SSH over the internet. 
The SSH port of that computer is not exposed so I first create a tunnel via a public resource (public ip).

```
ssh <public ip> -p 2022 -l root -L 127.1.1.1:2222:<private ip>:22
```

After that, I can create the SSH connection like this :

```
ssh username@127.1.1.1 -p 2222
```

Is it possible to execute this with a single command ?

Comment: This question is similar to this one http://superuser.com/questions/465423/redirect-all-ssh-traffic-through-a-middleman-server

Answer (score 1):

You could always just run the commands, one after the other:

```
ssh root@<public ip> -p 2022 -L 127.1.1.1:2222:<private ip>:22 && 
    ssh username@127.1.1.1 -p 2222
```

To spare yourself a lot of unnecessary typing, use bash aliases. Add a line like this to your `$HOME/.bashrc`:

```
alias ssh_tunnel='ssh <public ip> -p 2022 -l root -L 127.1.1.1:2222:<private ip>:22 && ssh username@127.1.1.1 -p 2222'
```

Now, open a new terminal and you can launch the tunnel and connect by running

```
ssh_tunnel
```

Comment: Just found out that this single command works : ssh -A -t root@<public ip> ssh -A -t <private ip> .  No need to do it in 2 steps apparently.

Comment: @ddewaele ah, makes sense, you give `ssh` as the command that `ssh` should run. Fair enough. I still recommend an alias though, saves a lot of typing.